python-docx: get document default font properties
I am writing a program which will read from a docx file and output formatted game code. Therefore, I need to gather all information I can from the docx document so I can design my program effectively. While reading paragraphs and gathering runs has been easy, I've run into the issue of python-docx returning None for properties which are "inherited from the style hierarchy." When encountering these None values, I am presented with an issue; because my program won't do anything with a None type, what value do I use instead? To remedy this, I am seeking a precise way to access an entire Document's default values for everything relating to paragraphs/fonts (if possible) such as: the default alignment, the default font, the default font size, the default font color, etc. With that said, can anyone provide any guidance on how I can achieve the behavior I am seeking (if it's worth seeking at all).
So far, I've been able to grab the default font size (I hope) using this method:
def _find_default_size(self, document):
        if(document != None and
        document.styles != None and
        document.styles.element != None):
            styles_elem = document.styles.element
            # print(et.tostring(styles_elem))

            default_LXML = styles_elem.xpath('w:docDefaults/w:rPrDefault')
            if(len(default_LXML) != 0 and
                len(default_LXML[0]) != 0):

                # https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/src/docx/oxml/text/font.py
                run = default_LXML[0][0] # Should be a type CT_RPr

                if(run.sz_val):
                    return run.sz_val.pt

        return -1

Which I originally found in this GitHub repo: https://github.com/pass-by-reference/doc-to-renpy/blob/main/renpy_doc_convert/to_renpy.py#L249 
While this method obtains the default font size, I am struggling to understand why it does, and struggling to gather other things like the default paragraph alignment, default font color, etc.
Furthermore, I'd like to add that I've tried converting the docx file to a zip file so I could try to find the locations of the desired default values manually, but nothing has stuck out so far :(
